# How to pass data between two activities in android?

Tags: android

How to pass data between two activities in android?

Following is my code:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SignoutActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", sessionId);
startActivity(intent)
```

Second I used SharedPreferences for that:-

For Pass Data:-

```
 SharedPreferences gameSettings = getSharedPreferences("MyGamePreferences",MODE_PRIVATE);  
 SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = gameSettings.edit();  
 prefEditor.putString("UserName", "Guest123");  
 prefEditor.putBoolean("PaidUser", false);  
 prefEditor.commit();
```

For Getting Data in next Activity:-

```
SharedPreferences gameSettings = PreferenceManager
                                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
String s= gameSettings.getString("UserName", "Dipak");
Boolean b= gameSettings.getBoolean("PaidUser", true);
```

but data is not getting in next activity.

Comment: You want to pass the data using putExtra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use mIntent.putExtra() for passing data to another activity?

Seeing your coding,you can get your sessionId in next activity using:(assuming your sessionId as integer)

```
int sessionId=getIntent().getIntExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID");
```

And the way you are getting values from SharedPreferences is absolutely correct.I don't know why you are not getting them in next activity.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
string dataToPass= "Hello I am activity one";
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtras("KeyToAccessData", dataToPass);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in the NextActivity, get the data like this:

```
String datatoCollect;
Intent intent = getIntent();
dataToCollect = intent.getStringExtra("KeyToAccessData");
```

If the data to pass is an object then you can check out [Parcelable](http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/)

Answer (score 2):

passing data between activity is by an intent object. You can use an object of Bundle class for attaching data to the intent object.
  find more about it from here http://codeglympse.blogspot.in/2012/10/passing-data-to-activity.html

Answer (score 1):

For first method use following line to get value

```
int sessionId=getIntent().getIntExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID");
```

For getting data using SP also you use this line

```
SharedPreferences gameSettings = getSharedPreferences("MyGamePreferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that doesn't work is because you're using two different preferences files. Use the default shared preferences in both places and it should work. However, if you just want to pass data, that's not the way to do it, you should just use more extras in your intent.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did,it works for me.

```
  Intent in = new Intent(this, SecondWindow.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("userName", "Name");
        bundle.putString("pwd", "password");
            in.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(in);
```

in the SecondWindow.java, onCreate method

```
 Bundle params = getIntent().getExtras();

        String username= params.getString("userName");
        String pwd= params.getString("pwd");
```